# reduce and map on accumulator produces stack overflow

Tags: clojure, stack-overflow, lazy-evaluation

Why do I need to replace `map` with `mapv`in this piece of code to prevent a stack overflow:

```
#!/bin/bash lein-exec                                                           


(println (reduce (fn [acc _]                                                    
                   ;;(mapv #(inc %) acc))                                       
                   (map #(inc %) acc))                                          
                 (repeat 2 0)                                                   
                 (range (long 1e6))))
```

~

I don't understand how the `acc` is processed when lazy. Thanks for insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, what you are getting is a large number of nested lazy sequences, which, when poked, cause a stack overflow.

Let's look at smaller example:

```
(reduce (fn [acc _]
          (map inc acc))
        (repeat 2 0)
        (range 3))
```

Since `map` is lazy, the result of above will be the next:

```
(map inc (map inc (map inc (0 0)))
```

So you are not eagerly mapping `acc` with `inc`, but only putting lazy sequences one into another, which will be realized afterwards.

Going back to the original example where `range` takes `1e6`, the result will be the following:

```
(map inc 
    (map inc 
         (<... rougly 1e6 nested lazy sequences here ...>
            (map inc (0 0))) ...)
```

Realizing of this will consume about `1e6` stack frames, which will definitely cause stack overflow.

In case of `mapv` laziness is not involved and `acc` is realized right away, so the result of your example will be `[1000000 1000000]` right after `reduce` finishes.